# How to manage property file in Sqoop scripts

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, sqoop

I need to provide certain user defined placeholders/parameters to a SQOOP script which at the execution time should be picked up.

For example my current sqoop script looks like:

```
sqoop job --create dummy_sqoop_job_name -- \
--options-file $USER_HOME/option_files/import.txt \
--password-file $USER_HOME/sqoop.password \
--table SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME \
--split-by SPLIT_KEY_COL \
--incremental append \
--check-column $CHECK_COLUMN \
--last-value $LAST_VALUE \
--target-dir $USER_HOME/staged/input/
```

I need to replace all placeholder starting with $ with the value from a property file.

Property file will be part of build packet.

Place holder can be anything, here I have taken $ to identify a placeholder.

Please let me know if I could achieve this in SQOOP or not

Comment: Just one more thing, I know we can set $USER_HOME or $HDFS_HOME in the profile of user.

Comment: If you are invoking Sqoop commands through shell script ,You can use source command to set the variables values  before sqoop command execution.